# congruence notation

Tags: abstract-algebra

Say we had $(p-1)! \equiv (-1)\mod p$ is this the same as saying $\overline{(p-1)!} = \overline{-1}$?

we defined $\overline{i}$ as the set of all integers congruent to $i$, so in this case $\overline{(p-1)!}$ is the set of integers $a \equiv (p-1)! \mod p$, and similarly $\overline{-1}$ is the set of integers $ b \equiv (-1) \mod p$ so if$\overline{(p-1)!} = \overline{-1}$ then $a \equiv (p-1)! \mod p = b \equiv (-1) \mod p $which is not $(p-1)! \equiv (-1) \mod p $, could someone explain the difference?

Comment: yes, They are same. Why do you have doubt?

Comment: @babgen I had doubt because of the definition of $\overline{i}$, it is the set of integers which are congruent to i, denote it a so $a \equiv i \mod p$, and if we do the same thing (which I done in my post, to $\overline{(p-1)!}$ and $\overline{-1}$ it doesn't look the same

Comment: $\overline{(p-1)!}=\{x|x=(p-1)! mod p\}$ and $\overline{-1}=\{x|x=-1 mod p\}$. if you have prove, then it needs some arguments.

Answer (score 1):

The notation with the bars denotes a equivalence class, which as you said, is the set of numbers congruent to each other in some modulo. Thus, $\overline{(p-1)!} = \overline{-1}$ indicates that the equivalence class that contains $-1$ modulo p is the the same as the one containing $(p-1)!$.

The congruence notation indicates that $(p-1)!+1 $ is divisible by p.

In the first case you are comparing sets of numbers, in the second you're making a statement about divisibility. Nonetheless, you can easily deduce both statements are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

They are the same provided that the modulo is understood. The first expression is understandable by itself, but the second one is not.